# How to set class to div tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing project in laravel. I have one variable $emails_unread_count which stores the unread emails which is a random. I want to add new class in the blade file to this number of divs  so that I can add css only for the unread emails and not for read once.
My blade file looks like,

**display.blade.php**

```
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            @foreach($data as $from)
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{$from->id}}">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{'collapse' . $from->id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{'collapse' . $from->id}}">
                                {{$from->from}}
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="{{'collapse' . $from->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{$from->id}}">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            {{$from->body}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

I want to add new class named as 'unread' to the "panel-heading" div. This class should be applied to the unread number of emails. Please give suggestions.

Comment: If you are okay to use jQuery then go ahead with @monace19 answer as that is the easiest. Or else Nero's answer as it is pure javascript

Comment: @Shweta Do you get the unread status from your database? (e.g $from->unread) or something like this?.

Comment: Nope!, i am still having that problem, I done some trial and error but, its not working

Comment: Is  $emails_unread_count an array? what data does it store actually ?

Comment: It stores number of unread emails, it is not array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change class for an element in javascript use:

```
 document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

To add an additional class to an element:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

Comment: i have to add class for unread emails only, and number of unread emails are stored in var `$emails_unread_count`. How can i relate them?

Comment: Actually, I add emails to my database, and then display it. i only store unread mails number to variable. so, the number stored in the var `$emails_unread_count` can help me?

Comment: u should have information about read and unread mails in database. get that info in $data and use it inside foreach loop to assign different classes for both

Answer (score 0):

use .addClass(). Here is the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
$("div.panel-heading").addClass("unread");
```

Comment: i have to add class for unread emails only, and number of unread emails are stored in var `$emails_unread_count`. How can i relate them?

Comment: you can add a condition inside your foreach. So that you can separate those unread and read emails.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "mystyle";

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
$('div.panel-heading').addClass('unread').removeClass('ifyouneedany');
```

**Note :**

Make sure you are doing this in document ready like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code here
  });
```

or in any proper click or some change functions